# "Found orphan containers" when starting DDEV project

Tags: ddev

I added a redis third-party service and tested it (see [redis example](https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/blob/master/docker-compose-services/redis).

Then I removed it. Now when I do a `ddev start` I see:

> Found orphan containers (ddev-d8composer-redis) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.

Answer (score 5):

I did a `docker container prune` and that seemed to fix it right up.  It didn't appear to delete anything else and ddev restart stopped complaining right away.

Comment: This removes containers from all stopped projects, not only the project with orphans.

Answer (score 3):

This message is coming from docker-compose and ddev doesn't have direct access to it. You can fix it with `ddev stop` or `ddev poweroff`, both of which will find the orphaned Docker container and shut it down.

(Note that this has nothing to do with redis; you can get this same message with any DDEV third-party service.)